# The following classes could not be found: - GestureOverlayView

Tags: android

I tried to insert a GesterOverlayView into my android application into the xml file and it says, `The following classes could not be found:- GestureOverlayView` And it wont let me work with the gestureOverlayview because of this error. I was following this guide: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html

Any reason why it may do this?

I use this code in my program and it still doesnt work. I get the error on the xml and the `addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);` part has an error but i copied it straight from  the google code.

```
GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
        gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will do it if you don't use the fully qualified name (android.gesture.GestureOverlayView). From the document:

> Notice that the GestureOverlayView is not part of the usual android.widget package. Therefore, you must use its fully qualified name.

Answer (score 0):

Brian Cooley is right, remember this is changed in you layout file, not your java code.

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView  
    android:id="@+id/gestures" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    ......
</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```